# BindingList, DataGridView and SQL Procedures

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to build simple data editor.
I've created simple application that uses DataGridView to edit data.
To hold my data objects I'm using BindingList. This way after adding new items my grid is able to show that new entry.
My form is working well, but now I must connect some data to it.
While loading is quite easy I have problem with adding new elements and updating.

I know that I could use SqlDataAdapter and DataTable, but I would like to use BindingList and automatically save all changes using stored procedures.

I've created some model classes:

```
public class Phone : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region AUTO
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, string propertyName)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
    #endregion

    public int PhoneId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string TypeTxt { get; set; }

    private bool _valid;
    public bool Valid
    {
        get { return _valid; }
        set { SetField(ref _valid, value, "Valid"); }
    }
}
```

Right now I only need to catch Valid change so I'm catching only this property change.

```
public class PhonesList : BindingList<Phone>
{
    public void AddNew(Phone newPhone)
    {
        //here I could call my sql procedure
        Add(newPhone);
    }
}
```

This class stores my phones, as in comments I could catch `add` inside `AddNew` method, but this way I must use `AddNew` instead of `Add`

And inside my main form:

```
    private readonly int _userId;
    private PhonesList _phones;

    private BindingSource _gridSource;

    private BindingSource GridSource
    {
        get { return _gridSource ?? (_gridSource = new BindingSource()); }
    }

    public PhoneDetails(int userId)
    {
        _userId = userId;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void PhoneDetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_applicationId == 0) return;
        _phones = DB.Instance.LoadPhones(_userId);

        GridSource.DataSource = _phones;
        phonesGV.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        phonesGV.DataSource = GridSource;
        _phones.ListChanged += _phones_ListChanged;
        _phones.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
        _phones_ListChanged(null, null);
    }

    void _phones_ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = string.Format("Phones - count: {0}", _phones.Count);
        Refresh();
    }

    private void addNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        errorProvider1.Clear();
        if(newPhoneNumberTb.Text.Length<9)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(newPhoneNumberTb,"9 digits minimum!");
            return;
        }
        if (newPhoneTypeCb.SelectedItem==null)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(newPhoneTypeCb, "Choose phone type!");
            return;
        }
        _phones.AddNew(new Phone
            {
                Number = newPhoneNumberTb.Text.Trim(),
                PhoneId = 0,
                Type = newPhoneTypeCb.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                TypeTxt = newPhoneTypeCb.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                Valid = true
            });
        newPhoneNumberTb.Text = "";
        newPhoneTypeCb.SelectedItem = null;
    }
```

I'm able to load data into my form using stored procedure, but right now I would like to call stored procedure that add new phone and update it when necessary.

Where should I listen for add/update "events"?
Is it correct to add add/update functionality to models?

Ideally I could add add/update to Phone Model, but this way I'll have problem with loading data, because every time I'll create instance my 'Add' query will be called.

Here is my LoadPhones:

```
    public PhonesList LoadPhones(int userId)
    {
        var phones = new PhonesList();

        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"LoadTelefonow", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@USER_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = userId;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 360;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        var phone = new Phone
                        {
                            PhoneId = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["Tel_Id"]),
                            Number = Convert.ToString(sdr["Number"]),
                            Type = Convert.ToString(sdr["Typ"]),
                            TypeTxt = Convert.ToString(sdr["Typ"]),
                            Valid = Convert.ToBoolean(sdr["Status"])
                        };
                        phones.Add(phone);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return phones;
    }
```

So my question is: Where and how should I add adding and updating functionality to my BindingList of my Phone model (don't know which one would be better)?

Answer (score 1):

**To Update:**

Using `BindingSource` as the `DataGridView`'s `DataSource` is good to be notified when a property changes inorder to update the corresponding item. You can do something like this:

In your MainForm or through designer:

```
datagridview1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
bindingSource1.CurrentItemChanged += new EventHandler(bindingSource1_CurrentItemChanged);
```

Declate a field in your form to maintain a list of changed items:

```
private List<int> UpdatedItemsIndex;
```

And add to it when something changes:

```
private void bindingSource1_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdatedItemsIndex.Add(bindingSource1.IndexOf(bindingSource1.Current));
}
```

**To Add:**
Likewise, use `BindingSource` and handles AddNew

```
bindingSource1.AddingNew += new System.ComponentModel.AddingNewEventHandler(this.bindingSource1_AddingNew);
```

And:

```
List<int> AddedItemsIndex = new List<int>();
private void bindingSource1_AddingNew(object sender, AddingNewEventArgs e)
{
    AddedItemsIndex .Add(bindingSource1.Count);
}
```

**To Save Changes**: Add/Update based on the lists. Remeber to clear them after they are inserted/updated.

Comment: I've tried `CurrentItemChanged` but it fires when I select different row in my grid, not when I update row (uncheck checkbox column for example), I've also tried `AddingNew` but it isn't firing.

Comment: `CurrentItemChanged` fires when a cell's edit is committed. Its changes commits for example when you leave the cell by moving to another cell or to another row. `AddingNew` should fires.

Comment: I can't get `AddingNew` to work. `CurrentItemChanged` works as You described (I imagine it to work different, but now is is clear). Can add add/update functionality be added to my `Phone` model? This way in every place of my application I'll be able to change property and correct row in db will be automatically updated.

Comment: Yes it can. But keeping it there is another story rather controls interaction